# What type of B-trees is actually used in SQL Server indices?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Many books on SQL Server and even [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190457.aspx) mention that SQL Server uses [B-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) to store indices. Recently I have learnt from the lecture on indices that [B+ trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree) are actually used.

Now I am totally confused.

To sum up:
Could you please give exact definition of B and B+ tree?
Please do it in plain English and if you are referring to other entities, please define those too.
And last but not least, what type of B-trees is used in SQL Server indices?

Comment: To answer the last part - SQL Server indexes are B+Trees - the lecturer is correct.

Comment: Yes @Andrew lecturer told that “Human babies are born by women”.

Comment: I had to read all of that and you just want to know the difference between a btree and a b+ tree?

Comment: Dear @Jeff O, I don't need your sarcasm on that. Maybe, there are other questions out there waiting for your precious attention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [B+-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree), records are stored only in leaves. In [B-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree), also in internal nodes.

Comment: Hi @Marcin. Thank you for your answer, but it does not really answer my question.

Comment: @Pavel Nefyodov I've added links, but if the lecture was good they should just be a summary (one of the best things of Wikipedia articles is all the links to relevant information and related articles). I really can't see any other question in the post. As the article point out, B+ trees are just a *kind* of B-trees -- it's like introducing a generic 'hash' in CS where when there is chaining, probing, extensible hashing, etc...

Comment: @pst Thank you very much for your post. There were no need to add links because there were in my question already. The lecture was on indices, not on B or B+ trees. B-trees were mentioned only ones "SQL Server stores indices in B+ trees". No more than that. That's why I wanted to clarify on this matter.